# $Z>0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[Z]>0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $Z \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{P})$ be an integrable random variable such that $Z>0$ everywhere. Does this imply that $\mathbb{E}[Z]>0$? I only know the statment where we replace "$>$" by "$\geq$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $\mathbb E[Z] = 0$, and $Z \ge 0$, then $Z=0$ except on a null set, which contradicts $Z > 0$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\varepsilon > 0$, Observe that $\varepsilon\cdot \mathbf 1(Z \geq \varepsilon) \leq Z$, therefore
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon\cdot\mathbb P[Z\geq \varepsilon]&=\mathbb E[\varepsilon\cdot\mathbf 1(Z \geq \varepsilon)]\\
&\leq \mathbb E[Z]
\end{align*}
Now suppose that $\mathbb E[Z]=0$, then for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\mathbb P[Z\geq \varepsilon]=0$, which means that \begin{align*}\mathbb P[Z=0]&=\mathbb P\left[\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\{Z < 1/n\}\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P[Z < 1/n]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} 1\\
&=1
\end{align*}